# is it legal to compare two variables with both Double.positive_infinity values?

Tags: java, double

in java, is it legal? i need to find points that are collinear with same slope to point of oigin. vertical lines have positive infinity slope. On cell phone, weird typing

Comment: Did it work when you tried?

Answer (score 6):

From the Java Language Specification

[15.20.1 Numerical Comparison Operators <, <=, >, and >=](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.20.1): "All values other than NaN are ordered, with negative infinity less than all finite values, and positive infinity greater than all finite values."

[15.21.1 Numerical Equality Operators == and !=](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.21.1): "In particular, there is one value representing positive infinity and one value representing negative infinity; each compares equal only to itself, and each compares unequal to all other values."

Answer (score 1):

Totally legal. POSITIVE_INFINITY *is* a value, after all.

EDIT 2: There used to be some stupid stuff in this post about Double.NaN. If you saw it, disregard it. `new Double(1.0 / 0.0).compareTo(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) = 0`, and POSITIVE_INFINITY equals itself, and that should be enough to handle vertical slopes.

Comment: Double.NaN and Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY are not the same concept at all.

Comment: Comment got deleted, but the gist of it was that compareTo() considers NaN > POSITIVE_INFINITY. Perhaps it's wrong, I don't know, but it makes sense to me.

Comment: Dividing a non zero value by zero does *not* return NaN... (but NaN is larger than infinity according to compareTo).

Comment: Double's compareTo is strange, because it absolutely has to represent a total order, and the  IEEE 754 binary float values are not naturally totally ordered. A NaN is not a number, but a placeholder for the direct or indirect result of a meaningless calculation. Is the real number square root of -1 greater or less than or equal to 3 times the result of dividing 0 by 0?

Comment: @assylias You're right. Guess there's a reason that comment was deleted :P